# flask admin custom QueryAjaxModelLoader

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

From what I understand, Flask Admin supports AJAX use for foreign key model loading. The [Flask Admin - Model Documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/) covers the basics under the heading `form_ajax_refs`. I have managed to use this successfully on many occasions, however I am having issues with the level of customisation that I hope to achieve. Let me elaborate.

I have a `Product` model, an `Organisation` model and a join table to relate them, defined as so:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    product_uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_seen = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, index=True)
    price = Column(Numeric(precision=7, scale=2), nullable=False, index=True)

class Organisation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "organisations"
    org_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    org_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    products = relationship(
        Product,
        secondary="organisation_products",
        backref="organisations"
    )

organisation_products_table = Table(
    "organisation_products",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("org_id", String, ForeignKey("organisations.org_id"), nullable=False),
    Column("product_uuid", UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("products.product_uuid"), nullable=False),
    UniqueConstraint("org_id", "product_uuid"),
    )
```

In a Flask Admin Model view of a model called `CuratedList` that has a foreign key constraint to the `Product` model, I am using `form_ajax_refs` in the form create view, to allow selection of dynamically loaded `Product` items.

```
form_ajax_refs = {"products": {"fields": (Product.title,)}}
```

This works nicely to show me ALL rows of the `Product` model.

My current requirement, however, is to **only use the AJAX model loader to show products with a specific org_id, for example "Google".**

### Attempt No. 1

Override `get_query` function of the `ModelView` class to join on `organisation_products_table` and filter by `org_id`. This looks something like this:

```
def get_query(self):
    return (
        self.session.query(CuratedList)
        .join(
            curated_list_items_table,
            curated_list_items_table.c.list_uuid == CuratedList.list_uuid
        )
        .join(
            Product,
            Product.product_uuid == curated_list_items_table.c.product_uuid
        )
        .join(
            organisation_products_table,
            organisation_products_table.c.product_uuid == Product.product_uuid
        )
        .filter(CuratedList.org_id == "Google")
        .filter(organisation_products_table.c.org_id == "Google")
    )
```

Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue, and returns the same behaviour as:

```
def get_query(self):
    return (
        self.session.query(CuratedList)
        .filter(CuratedList.org_id == self._org_id)
    )
```

It does not affect the behaviour of `form_ajax_refs`.

### Attempt No.2

The [Flask Admin - Model Documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/) mentions another way of using `form_ajax_refs`, which involves using the `QueryAjaxModelLoader` class.

In my second attempt, I subclass the `QueryAjaxModelLoader` class and try to override the values of it's `model`, `session` or `fields` variables. Something like this:

```
class ProductAjaxModelLoader(QueryAjaxModelLoader):
    def __init__(self, name, session, model, **options):
        super(ProductAjaxModelLoader, self).__init__(name, session, model, **options)

        fields = (
            session.query(model.title)
            .join(organisation_products_table)
            .filter(organisation_products_table.c.org_id == "Google")
        ).all()

        self.fields = fields
        self.model = model
        self.session = session
```

And then instead of the previous `form_ajax_refs` approach, I use my new `AjaxModelLoader` like so:

```
form_ajax_refs = {
    "products": ProductAjaxModelLoader(
        "products", db.session, Product, fields=['title']
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, whether overriding the values of `session` or `model` with my query returns no products from the AJAX loader, and overriding `fields` still returns all products; not just products of org_id "Google".

### What I Hope to Not Resort to

I would like to be able to achieve this **without** having to create a new model for each org, as this will prove to be non-scalable and of bad design.

Any suggestions welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Here's how AjaxModelLoader class looks like: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/ajax.py#L4

All you have to do is to override `get_list` method and apply your filters using this as an foundation: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/ajax.py#L58

Comment: Nice question. Would love it if flask-admin incorporated a generic way of constraining a field value depending on another field's value. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Joes comment to my original question, I have formulated a working solution:

Override `AjaxModelLoader` function `get_list` like so:

```
def get_list(self, term, offset=0, limit=DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE):
    filters = list(
        field.ilike(u'%%%s%%' % term) for field in self._cached_fields
    )
    filters.append(Organisation.org_id == "Google")
    return (
        db.session.query(Product)
        .join(organisation_products_table)
        .join(Organisation)
        .filter(*filters)
        .all()
    )
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this based on using another field rather than a static string ('Google' above), i.e. i select organisation in one field and then based on that the dropdown for products is able to filter based on the id for example.

Comment: It would be a lot more feasible to first store the selected field in the model, as opposed to having the drop down dynamically populate with the contents of other fields in the same form. In this case, I would create a separate model view to store organisations. Otherwise, you might be looking at doing some custom Javascript.

Comment: I thought it would be, i was hoping you might have needed to and had already done the hard work :) I'll have a go at making a generic solution as i need this for my administrative portal in several different contexts.

Comment: I managed to achieve this quite generically i think. From QueryAjaxModelLoader i modified __init__ to accept and additional filter arg, i also overrode get_list to and_ the filter. To generate the form i had to modify AjaxSelect2Widget __call__ to ensure ensure my filter field got added to the generated html. Finally i modified form-1.0.0.js processAjaxWidget to pass back the filter info as part of the query,

Comment: @nickjb If you were able to share a gist that would be tremendously helpful. Constraining field values based on the value of another field must be a widespread need.

Comment: Sure, i'll try and put something up later

Comment: @zx81 I think my answer it about what you were talking about posting... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50534284/999943

Answer (score 4):

After much trial and error, and thanks to the posts above, I present a generic way to pass in filters to the Ajax Model Loader.

Here is a generic class that enables filtering on the foreign key table.

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ajax import QueryAjaxModelLoader, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE

class FilteredAjaxModelLoader(QueryAjaxModelLoader):
    additional_filters = []

    def get_list(self, term, offset=0, limit=DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE):
        filters = list(
            field.ilike(u'%%%s%%' % term) for field in self._cached_fields
        )
        for f in self.additional_filters:
            filters.append(f)
        # filters.append(User.list_id == 2) # Now this is passed in the constructor
        # filters.append(User.is_active == 'Y')
        return (
            db.session.query(self.model)
                .filter(*filters)
                .all()
        )

    def __init__(self, name, session, model, **options):
        super(FilteredAjaxModelLoader, self).__init__(name, session, model, **options)
        self.additional_filters = options.get('filters')
```

Usage:

Pass it into `form_ajax_refs` like you would [`QueryAjaxModelLoader`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_ajax_refs)

```
FilteredAjaxModelLoader('component', db.session, User, fields=['list_value'],
                                filters=[User.list_id == 2, User.is_active == 'Y'])
```

Hope that helps.